# Sort sub documents in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var fileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    type            : String,
    batch           : String,
    client          : String,
    id              : Number,
    name            : String,
   }, { collection: 'attest' });

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name         : String,
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
        role         : String,
        files        : [fileSchema]
    }, { collection: 'attest' });
```

These are two parent and child schema I have. How can I sort the "files" based on "type" field? type field keeps changing, so sorting while populating wont help. I am using expressjs and angular